# How can I correctly customize my Bootstrap variables with SASS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-5

So I already have a created web page and I have added Bootstrap styling into it. I am now in the process of customizing the Bootstrap variables but it does not seem to work at all and no errors are being shown.

I have already followed a tutorial from Youtube step-by-step but it does not work at all. Here are the steps that I have followed:

1. Make sure that the web page is ready and is already styled with Bootstrap
2. Install SASS through NPM
3. Create a custom bootstrap.scss and bootstrap.css file
4. Link the custom bootstrap.css file to the index file
5. Imported the bootstrap.scss file to the custom bootstrap.scss file
6. Customized the variables needed then saved the file.
7. Then type in the terminal: `sass custom-bootstrap.scss custom-bootstrap.css`

I have the following code written in my `custom-bootstrap.scss` file:

```
$primary: #2F3061;
$warning: #FFE66D;

@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

I have already tried looking for the same problem here in stack and tried the solutions but it still does not work. I have already made sure that my `custom-bootstrap.css` has the variables overriden, with the same values as the custom one.

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand two things about this:

1. CSS has the rule of the last to load is the rule used

```css
.flex{
display: flex; // this will be ignored
}

.flex{
display: block; // this will be used
}
```

2. This is also true for different CSS files Ex.:

```css
// file1.css - loaded BEFORE file2.css
.flex{
display: flex; // this will be ignored
}
```

```css
//file2.css - loaded AFTER file1.css
.flex{
display: block; // this will be used
}
```

Simple enough right? The thing is, if you are fetching bootstrap css files AFTER you fetch your custom css files, then bootstrap files takes precedence over yours.

How to fix this?

- Move the import of the bootstrap file BEFORE your custom code, so whatever you are writing after will actually override Bootstrap file and not the opposite

P.S.: I strongly suggest you move away from bootstrap, it's not optimized for the new web and does give you strong headaches later on. If you are used to the class system, migrate to tailwind, it's AWESOME, first is weird but then you can't drop it anymore.

Comment: Actually, I have already tried your solution of importing Bootstrap BEFORE my custom code before asking here in Stack and it also does not work. Also, thanks for your suggestion. I actually have already been dabbling a bit on Tailwind.